# When using IBM iSeries Client Access to create a .CSV file from an AS400 db file, can I squeeze out leading blanks?

Tags: csv, export-to-csv, ibm-midrange, data-transfer

> I have a very simple iseries AS400 DDS file defined in this way

```
A    R U110055R                  TEXT('POSITIVE PAY') 
A            ACCT55   9A 
A            SERL55        10A 
A            ISSD55        10A 
A            AMT55         13A 
A            NAME55        50A
```

> I am using Data Transfer from System i (IBM I Access for Windows V6R1)
>   to output a csv to the desktop.  It will then be used by our banking
>   PC software.  I cannot find a setting or a file type that will yield
>   the data without leading blanks.  It consistently holds the file sizes
>   of the Database file (without trailing blanks).
>
> I need:

```
  "192345678","311","07/22/2016","417700","ALICE BROWN CO."
  "192345678","2887","07/22/2016","4124781","BARBIE LLC."
  "192345678","2888","07/22/2016","4766","ROBERT BLUE, INC."
  "192345678","2889","07/22/2016","71521","NANCYS COOKIES, INC"
  "192345678","312","07/22/2016","67041","FRANKS MARKET"
```

> But I get:

```
 "192345678","       311","07/22/2016","     11417700","ALICE BROWN CO."
 "192345678","       887","07/22/2016","      4124781","BARBIE LLC." 
 "192345678","       888","07/22/2016","      3204766","ROBERT BLUE, INC." 
 "192345678","       301","07/22/2016","      2971521","NANCY, INC" 
 "192345678","       890","07/22/2016","       967041","FRANKS MARKET"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The <kbd>Data Options</kbd> button of the Data Transfer from IBM i application brings up a window where you can explicitly specify the SQL statement used to extract data.

You can use the SQL `TRIM()` function there...
[image]

Comment: Thanks SO much!  I knew there had to be a setting!  NOW. if we could just TRIM off leading zeros in a text field - My users would be off & running & I'd be making progress on other things!

Comment: @Sooze, use `TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM name)`

Comment: @sooze, I want to bulk export export using IBM iseries. Is ther any possibility

Answer (score 1):

**Limitation of DDS:**

[Use of TRIM in DDS](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/23778490/Use-of-TRIM-in-DDS-Logical-File-declaration.html)

> The answer seems to be **"You can't."** If I were doing this, I'd probably
>   **create a SQL VIEW** with a DDL statement rather than try to get it done
>   with DDS.

**Solution:** ([W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp)) or ([IBM Knowledge Center](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzhcview.htm))

```
CREATE VIEW U110055V1 as
    SELECT  TRIM(ACCT55),
            TRIM(SERL55),
            TRIM(ISSD55),
            TRIM(AMT55),
            TRIM(NAME55)
    FROM U110055
    RCDFMT U110055V1R;
```

**Suggestion:**

- Export the newly created View to a .CSV file ([refer here](http://www.rpgpgm.com/2013/11/zipping-files-in-ifs.html) or [here](http://www.rpgpgm.com/2014/05/adding-column-headings-to-file-in-ifs.html))
- Share the IFS file on the network for easy consistent automated access, (No manual export with i Access required).

Comment: I don't think the database file that is being exported is in the IFS, thus the need to export it.

Comment: The Table file is not in the IFS, the newly created csv which is a Stearm file should be generated into the IFS.

Comment: I would do it that way too.  No sense hiding business logic inside a data transfer.

Comment: Thanks ya'll!!  All I really needed was the data transfer info!  All of the other programming has been in place for a while.  We have multiple banks that have required flat files - fixed length.  A newer vendor wanted same data in .csv.  THANKS!

Comment: ps.  You are correct the data file DID NOT reside on the IFS and I didn't really want to involve the IFS and put it there, either.

Comment: @Sooze It's just picking a nit, but **all** files of all types reside "on the IFS" of your server, including DB2 tables. Even your compiled *PGM objects are in the IFS. The IFS covers all of the space that you can access, even libraries.